# How to digitally sign the Application.exe during publish in MAUI?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exe, maui

We want to publish the MAUI application after digitally signing the Application main .DLL and .EXE Files using DigiCert Hardware token certificate.

Steps we followed is:

1. Re-Build the Project in Release Mode
2. Digitally Sign the respective file of DLL and Exe present in Bin and Obj folder through DigiCert Hardware Token
3. Publish the project in Release Mode
4. During publish it has option to add Certificate, so we add the DigiCert respective certificate (so that it signs the msix file after publishing).

After Step 4 the Package (MSIX file) is successfully created with Digital Signature and ready to install.

Post installation, the Application files are present in C:\Programs Files\WindowsApps folder, over here the Digital signature is not found in EXE File i.e. Digital signature from EXE file gets removed but digital signature is present in DLL file.

We tried with POST BUILD events also, before publishing the Digital signature is present in EXE and DLL, but after publishing the Digital signature gets removed from EXE.

We want to keep digital signature on both dll as well as on exe. Please provide your suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to unpack the msix package using makeappx.exe, sign application.exe and application.dll using signtool.exe and pack it again into msix package and sign the msix package again.

Here is a basic working PowerShell script.

```
try {
    $CurrentDirectory = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
    Set-Location -Path $CurrentDirectory
    
    # Set Environment Variable to your Windows Kit so signtool and makeappx.exe could be found
    $env:PATH += ";C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64\"
    
    # script assume it will run from same directory as msix package and there will be only 1 msix.
    $MsixFile = Get-ChildItem $buildFolderPath -Filter "*.msix" | Select-Object -First 1

    # Important: FolderName should match with MSIX file Name
    $MsixFolderName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($MsixFile.Name)
    $UnpackFolderPath = Join-Path -Path $CurrentDirectory -ChildPath ("UnpackFolder\$MsixFolderName")

    $DllFilePath = Join-Path -Path $UnpackFolderPath "MyMauiApp.dll"
    $AppFilePath = Join-Path -Path $UnpackFolderPath "MyMauiApp.exe"

    mkdir $UnpackFolderPath
    # Unpack the MSIX to a temp folder created.
    makeappx.exe unpack /d $UnpackFolderPath /p $MsixFile.FullName

    # Backup orginal MSIX
    $BackupMsixPath = $MsixFile.FullName + ".bak"
    Rename-Item -Path $MsixFile.FullName -NewName $BackupMsixPath

    # Sign MyMauiApp.dll
    signtool.exe sign /fd SHA256 /a /t http://timestamp.digicert.com /n "Certificate Common Name" $DllFilePath

    #Sign MyMauiApp.exe
    signtool.exe sign /fd SHA256 /a /t http://timestamp.digicert.com /n "Certificate Common Name" $AppFilePath

    #Pack MSIX package.
    makeappx.exe pack /d $UnpackFolderPath /p $MsixFile.FullName

    #Sign MSIX package.
    signtool.exe sign /fd SHA256 /a /t http://timestamp.digicert.com /n "Certificate Common Name" $MsixFile.FullName
}
catch {
    Write-Error "Failed to sign"
}
```